# Call REST web service URL from the browser

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat, cxf

I have deployed simple REST interface. Lets say my REST service is deployed in this context path:

```
http://localhost:8080/Engine/services/Evaluation
```

Then I invoke URL like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/Engine/services/Evaluation?_wadl
```

I can see the XML output:

```
<application>
    <grammars/>
    <resources base="http://localhost:8080/Engine/services/Evaluation">
        <resource path="/Evaluation/">
            <resource path="initializeEvaluation/{localeCode}">
                <param name="localeCode" style="template" type="xs:string"/>
                <method name="GET">
                    <request>
                        <representation mediaType="application/octet-stream"/>
                    </request>
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
            </resource>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</application>
```

The question is how to call the method with the URL from the browser?

I've tried to enter:

```
http://localhost:8080/Engine/services/Evaluation/initializeEvaluation?localeCode=en-GB
```

But I've got:

```
2013-01-30 11:22:13,477 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] WARN   JAXRSInInterceptor - No root resource matching request path /Engine/services/Evaluation/initializeEvaluation has been found, Relative Path: /initializeEvaluation. Please enable FINE/TRACE log level for more details.
2013-01-30 11:22:13,479 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] WARN   WebApplicationExceptionMapper - javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException
```

I am very new at REST but as far as I understand the URL should be like above. Why then I am getting and exception?

My java interface:

```
@Path("/Evaluation/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public interface EvaluationService {

    @GET
    @Path("initializeEvaluation/{localeCode}")
    EvaluationStatus initializeEvaluation(ClientType client, @PathParam("localeCode") String localeCode)
            throws EvaluationException;

}
```

I am using Apache CXF 2.7.0, JDK 1.7, Tomcat 7.

Comment: `@Path("initializeEvaluation/{localeCode}")` to `@Path("\initializeEvaluation/{localeCode}")`

Comment: Getting syntax error about the incorrect character: `\\`.

Comment: its `@Path("/initializeEvaluation/{localeCode}")`

Comment: Web Services and WADL are nothing to do with REST. Jim, please read this: http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven and this: http://nordsc.com/ext/classification_of_http_based_apis.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a path param.  Thus, I believe the URL should be:

```
http://localhost:8080/Engine/services/Evaluation/initializeEvaluation/en-GB
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a / in your @Path annotation.

```
@Path("/initializeEvaluation/{localeCode}")
```

Comment: The same error. Please note that I have `/` on `@Path("/Evaluation/")`, so I don't need it on the method.

Answer (score 0):

Use [RestClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/restclient/) plugin , it makes your life easier.