# is it possible to have same class for both soap and rest in cxf

Tags: java, spring, web-services, cxf, jax-rs

I am trying to configure a way to serve same class for soap and rest in different paths.
I am following the project structure described here

[spring-cxf-example link](http://pfelitti87.blogspot.in/2012/05/webservices-with-spring-apache-cxf.html) with the code downloaded from [SVN project link](https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/pablo-examples/spring-cxf-example/)

Following is the class

```
package ar.com.pabloExample.services;

import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "ar.com.pabloExample.services.HelloWorldService")
public class HelloWorldServiceBean implements HelloWorldService {

    @Override
        @GET       
    public String sayHello(String name) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!!!");
                return "Hello World Returned From Service"+ " for "+name;
    }

}
```

and following is the context configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
       xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
                http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:service-definition-beans.xml"/>

    <jaxws:endpoint id="helloWorld" implementor="#helloWorldService" address="/HelloWorld" />
    <jaxrs:server id="helloWorldRs" address="/rest/helloworld">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>                       
            <ref bean="helloWorldService" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    </jaxrs:server>

</beans>
```

and I am trying to invoke the service from the spring test class as below.

```
import ar.com.pabloExample.services.HelloWorldService;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/service-definition-beans-test.xml"})
public class HelloWorldServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("helloWorldClient")
    private HelloWorldService helloWorldClient;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("helloworldrestclient")
    private HelloWorldService helloworldrestclient;

    @Test
    public void helloWorldClientTest() {

        System.out.println(helloWorldClient.sayHello("SOAP user"));
        System.out.println(helloworldrestclient.sayHello("REST user"));
    }
}
```

with test application context configuration like the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
       xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
                http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">

    <jaxws:client id="helloWorldClient" serviceClass="ar.com.pabloExample.services.HelloWorldService"
        address="http://localhost:8080/spring-cxf-example/HelloWorld" />
        <jaxrs:client id="helloworldrestclient" serviceClass="ar.com.pabloExample.services.HelloWorldService" address="http://localhost:8080/spring-cxf-example/rest/helloworld"/>

</beans>
```

but the jaxrs:client fails to load with error

```
     T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running ar.com.pabloExamples.test.HelloWorldServiceTest
Jul 08, 2013 2:40:16 PM org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager retrieveTestExecutionListeners
INFO: @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [class ar.com.pabloExamples.test.HelloWorldServiceTest]: using defaults.
Jul 08, 2013 2:40:16 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [service-definition-beans-test.xml]
Jul 08, 2013 2:40:17 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@d11816: startup date [Mon Jul 08 14:40:16 IST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Jul 08, 2013 2:40:17 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1c0070f: defining beans [helloWorldClient.proxyFactory,helloWorldClient,helloworldrestclient.proxyFactory,helloworldrestclient,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
Jul 08, 2013 2:40:17 PM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.ResourceUtils checkMethodDispatcher
WARNING: No resource methods have been found for resource class ar.com.pabloExample.services.HelloWorldService
Jul 08, 2013 2:40:17 PM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean checkResources
SEVERE: No resource classes found
Jul 08, 2013 2:40:17 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1c0070f: defining beans [helloWorldClient.proxyFactory,helloWorldClient,helloworldrestclient.proxyFactory,helloworldrestclient,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
Jul 08, 2013 2:40:17 PM org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager prepareTestInstance
SEVERE: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1df5801] to prepare test instance [ar.com.pabloExamples.test.HelloWorldServiceTest@ae308]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'helloworldrestclient': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.Client org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean.create()] threw exception; nested exception is javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1015)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:103)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(DelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:228)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.Client org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean.create()] threw exception; nested exception is javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:169)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570)
        ... 46 more
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.checkResources(AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.java:312)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean.createWithValues(JAXRSClientFactoryBean.java:253)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean.create(JAXRSClientFactoryBean.java:241)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:149)
        ... 47 more

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.167 sec <<< FAILURE!

Results :

Tests in error: 
  helloWorldClientTest(ar.com.pabloExamples.test.HelloWorldServiceTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.701s
```

but it works with soap while restclient is removed from configuration and test class.

While I check the URL in the browser I am getting listing of both WSDL and WADL so may be server is set up correctly. What am I doing wrong?

As pointed out by Paulius Matulionis I updated to the latest 2.7.5 from 2.6.x I was using earlier and now I am getting the following error

```
SEVERE: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@a5d04b] to prepare test instance [ar.com.pabloExamples.test.HelloWorldServiceTest@dffbf]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'helloworldrestclient': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.Client org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean.create()] threw exception; nested exception is javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1015)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:103)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(DelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:228)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.Client org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean.create()] threw exception; nested exception is javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:169)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570)
        ... 46 more
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.checkResources(AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.java:319)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean.createWithValues(JAXRSClientFactoryBean.java:275)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean.create(JAXRSClientFactoryBean.java:262)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:149)
        ... 47 more

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.124 sec <<< FAILURE!

Results :

Tests in error: 
  helloWorldClientTest(ar.com.pabloExamples.test.HelloWorldServiceTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
```

Comment: The exception is incomplete (it ends with `JAXRSClientFac`). Could you please edit your question to include the complete exception?

Comment: hi, I have added the full stacktrace

Comment: Which version of CXF you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit of googling what this exception `Caused by: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException` might mean pointed me to the similar issue:

http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/cxf-spring-jax-rs-client-Caused-by-javax-ws-rs-WebApplicationException-td5727458.html

Most likely you are not using the latest CXF and the option using `jaxrs:client` is not supported in versions below `2.7.5`. Try to updated your CXF to `2.7.5` (latest version) and it should work.

Comment: yes, updating to 2.7.5 fixes the error but introduces another one.Not sure but is it the case described here? [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602877/call-rest-web-service-url-from-the-browser[/link]