# Webservices that support both Rest+JSON and SOAP

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, jersey, cxf

I need to come up with a set up of webservices. Some of the clients want to call it the REST-JSON way. Some others in the SOAP way. I would like to write only one set of code. On top of that, using come config parameters , the output format should change. In other words, the SOAP client will pass the SOAP input XML and will get a SOAP output XML. For the other clients , it will be JSON. 
What are my options here ?

Comment: SOAP and REST is not aobut XML and JSON. A RESTful application is about Resources. SOAP basically is RPC.

Answer (score 2):

Not repeating yourself is usually good, but it can make things complex.
Remote-Interfaces are complex enough, so mixing technologies to reduce a few lines of code may make your interface non-maintainable (at all).

As you only ask generally I can only give you a general answer.

First there is a similar post that will bring you further on the technical layer:

[is it possible to have same class for both soap and rest in cxf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522997/is-it-possible-to-have-same-class-for-both-soap-and-rest-in-cxf?rq=1)

But there are other questions that you should answer yourself as well:

- what your service(s) shall do (Use cases).
- where to make your cuts.

You use Spring (or Jersy MK2) , so using IoC will help you greatly in making nice cuts.

As you might exspect I do suggest making two different WS-Endpoints. One for REST and one for SOAP.
It might look counter intuitive first, but my reasoning is simple:

- Too many annotations hide what your stuff is doing.
- You might have different technical needs - or these develop over time
- Separation of Concerns reduces testing times.

Writing two consumers for your backend give you a better feeling on "how good" your backend is - and how akward your usecases are.

The examples behind that link above do not feel complex enough to be "real world" cases.
It simply looks to good doing that.

Once you start doing some major mojo with security, billing, monitoring, tracking ... the amount annotations will pile up in a strange way.

And last-but-not-least: What makes Sense in a REST way does not need to make sense in a SOAP way and vice versa.